# Error while adding SharePoint web service reference

Tags: 2010, development, web-services, spservices

I got stuck up with the following error, while trying to add reference for the web service Lists.asmx in sharepoint 2010 from VS.NET 2010.

> The document at the url
>   http://sp2010/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx was
>   not recognized as a known document
>   type. Metadata contains a reference
>   that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://sp2010/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx'.
>   The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was 'NTLM'.
>   The remote server returned an error:
>   (401) Unauthorized. If the service is
>   defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the
>   service reference again.

In our development environment SP2010 is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2, the same machine is being used for development purpose.

I had tried the following steps to sort this out, but didn't get resolved.

1. I was able to view the functions exposed by the webservice, after pasting the webservice URL "http://sp2010/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx" onto the browser on the same machine,
2. I tried to pass the username\password details before referring the service but didn't find any option in VS.NET 2010.

Please help.

**Update:**
**Solution:** Finally I created a new web application in sharepoint with anonymous authentication and created the site collection and root sites after that. Now the webservice is working perfectly fine, still don't what went wrong previously. 
Guys thanks for all your suggestions, from which I came to learn new troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new web application in sharepoint with anonymous authentication and created the site collection and root sites after that. Now the webservice is working perfectly fine, still don't what went wrong previously. Guys thanks for all your suggestions, from which I came to learn new troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving the complete path to your site and appending the WSDL parameter:

```
http://sp2010/sites/mysitecollection/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WDSL
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be the infamous loopback check. FGor more info check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;896861).

Comment: As you said, I added the "DisableLoopbackCheck" entry in registry and restarted the machine, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Add Service Reference dialog? If so, try clicking the Advanced button and then using Add Web Reference instead.

Comment: Yes I tried that too, but still the same problem. Anyhow thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions are described [in on my SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963931/401-iis-error-for-searchadmin-asmx/5035520#5035520).

To resume, two potential issues : http 401.1 or 402.1 error codes.

The former is due to the NTLM protocol, the later to the double hop disabled locally by default?.

Comment: I came to saw you solution while searching for the aforesaid problem, anyhow thank you very much for responding to my query.

Comment: happy to help, happy to be helped eventually :)