# Can not see /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL xml file

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

I'm trying to add web services with Visual Studio, I always got the following error:

> The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>           Metadata contains a reference that can not be resolved: 
>          `http://server:port/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL`. 
>          The HTTP request is not allowed with customer authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

When I try to browse the web services `http://server:port/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL` xml file, I see a blank page. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using SP 2010 or 2013?

Comment: i use sharepoint 2013

Comment: Depending on your browser it could display the XML response from requesting the WSDL as a blank page. If you right click and select View Source on the page it should show the WSDL response.

Answer (score 1):

As you will need permission to access that resources adding the reference will need to be done from an account that has permission to SharePoint.

Did you try starting Visual Studio as an Administrator, if that administrator account has permissions to the SharePoint server?

Else you could try to use the runas comman to start visual studio under any account you want and try to add the reference.

Edit:
Here is some one with what looks like the same issue as you. The solution for him was to create a new Web Application with Anonymous Authentication activated.
[Error while adding SharePoint web service reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14198/error-while-adding-sharepoint-web-service-reference)

Hope it helps

Comment: visual studio started as Administrator and i'm the site admin

Comment: Please view my edit and see if it helps.

Comment: Oh by the way how are you adding the reference in VS? are you trying to add a Service Reference or are you adding a Web Reference?

Comment: i'm trying service reference

Comment: The Service Reference one if for WCF services. To add a reference to SharePoint's asmx services you will have to use add Web Reference> open the Add Service Reference dialogue and click on the Advanced, then Add Web Reference and it should work.

Comment: yeah i did that but the last window button add reference is deactivated

Comment: What is the error message you get when lookup up the services in the window? And did you add ?wsdl to the end of the URL when looking the services up in the Add Web Reference window?

Answer (score 0):

It can be that the SharePoint installer doesn't correctly configure .NET 4 WCF components correctly.

The installer installed and configured IIS, and the "SharePoint Web Services" site, but fails to install and configure WCF Process Activation completely. After installing and configuring these components (Server Manager > Add Features > .NET Framework 4 > WCF Process Activation), a new error sprung up, which can be addressed by installing update KB2567680.

Reference: http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/workitem/18755

After installing both the missing components and the Windows Update, search topology loads and everything should working properly.